# How to solve this error : must specify valid information for parsing in the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to convert a string to enum . My code is like this

```
   var categoryEnum = (SiteCategory) Enum.Parse(typeof (SiteCategory), UIController.QueryStringParamInitialValue, true);
```

And **QueryStringParamInitialValue**() is like this

```
   public static string QueryStringParamInitialValue
    {
        get
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["UIController_QueryStringParamInitialValue"] != null)
                str = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Session["UIController_QueryStringParamInitialValue"] as string);
            return str;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UIController_QueryStringParamInitialValue"] = (object)HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(value);
        }
    }
```

I am facing error in  **var categoryEnum = (SiteCategory) Enum.Parse(typeof (SiteCategory), UIController.QueryStringParamInitialValue, true);**

Any information regarding this will be helpful..pls help

Comment: What error exactly? Have you used the debugger in `QueryStringParamInitialValue`?

Comment: What is your enum? What is the value of the string?

Comment: In the case that empty string was generated by QueryStringParamInitialValue, how will it be parse to `SiteCategory`?

Comment: thanks for reply John Woo,Tim,Stephen. QueryStringParamInitialValue is empy I just checked .

Answer (score 0):

*If seeing this error as a part of a Xamarin project:*

[As mentioned here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80565/building-ios-projects-fails-suddenly-for-all-projects) I had to **"launch xCode at least one time after it's update."** for this error to go away.  I also had to restart Visual Studio after the xCode update and launch.